# Flex 3: possible to run a function after a repeater is completed done loading the children?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, repeater

I have a repeater which creates a child named "wholeProject" each time the repeater loops.

```
<mx:Repeater id="projectRP" dataProvider="{projectsHttp.lastResult.project}">
    <Block:project 
        id="wholeProject"
        oneDay="{(usableSize.width - 16)/14}"
        projectID="{projectRP.currentIndex}"
        creationComplete="getConflicts('project', 'l', false); getStudentYears();"
    />
</mx:Repeater>
```

As you can see from the last line of the  piece, i have a the creationComplete option run two functions.  What I would LIKE to happen is once the repeater is done loading all of the block:project pieces for each function to run once and only once.  Instead, the two functions are running after each  is created.  I tried putting the creation complete in the  tag, but that didn't work.

Is there a way to tell the creationComplete piece to run only when the last piece of the repeater has been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check out the [repeatEnd](http://docs.huihoo.com/flex/4/mx/core/Repeater.html#event%3arepeatEnd) event

```
<mx:Repeater ... repeatEnd="repeatEndHandler(event)">
...
</mx:Repeater>
```

Comment: Thanks... it worked (running the function(s) after the repeater was finished, but for some reason, it function no longer works... :(.  I'm sure i can work with it from here though, thanks a bunch!